# Fallback value if null in c++

Tags: c++

In javascript I can write the following:

```js
const bar = getBar();
const foo = bar || 0;
```

If `getBar()` returns a null value, foo will fallback to 0.

In C++ I could do this:

```cpp
auto bar = getBar();
int foo = bar? bar: 0;
```

But is there a more concise way of doing this in C++?

Comment: as written the second line is the same as `int foo = bar;`. Only if `bar == 0` you assign `0` instead of `bar`s value. Did you actually mean `int foo = bar ? *bar : 0;` ?

Comment: You can write your own `or_null` function to do this.

Comment: It will depend on the type `getBar()` returns.

Comment: What is the purpose of `foo`? How will it be used? What problem is it supposed to solve that isn't possible by checking `bar` directly?

Comment: Also remember that C++ doesn't have the concept of null "values", though they can be emulated using e.g. `std::optional` or pointers.

Comment: g++ and clang have a language extension, where you can omit the "true" case and it returns the value of the condition: ```int foo = bar ?: 0;``` but it's intended for cases where the true case is expensive to compute or is a long expression and you don't want to duplicate it.

Comment: Understanding the question very strictly, `int foo = getBar();` is the answer. If `getBar()` returns a "null" value and the return type is compatible with `int` as your solution suggests, then `foo` will be assigned `0`.

Comment: `Foo* p = GetFoo(); int i = p ? p->GetValue() : 0;` or `std::optional<int> x = GetOptInt(); int i = x ? *x : 0;`